# How to install TestDisk from source

Tags: 12.04, install-from-source, tar, testdisk

I have just come downloading a software called `testdisk-6.14-WIP.linux26.tar.bz2`. Therefore I'm wondering how to deal with the installation.

Answer (score 6):

testdisk is in the ubuntu repositories

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Installing from the repositories is the prefered method.

You may need to enable the universe repository.

[image: Universe]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: For 12.04 and later, you probably won't need to enable Universe, as it is usually enabled.

Answer (score 4):

From [their Step by Step wiki](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), you just have to untar the file:

```
tar xvjf testdisk-6.14-WIP.linux26.tar.bz2
```

and then run as root, e.g.:

```
sudo testdisk-6.14/testdisk_static
```